# git stash and git stash apply without clearing working directory momentarily

Tags: git

Many times I need to take a snapshot of the current working directory as a backup before making experimental changes. Here is what I do.

```
git stash
git stash apply
```

But I used some applications that listen for disk changes and they cause unwanted behavior. I want to do the same without cleaning the local working directory in the first step.

It can be a line of code or a multi-line string as I will just create a function for it.

Bonus: Nice if it preserves the current staging/non-staging area too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
git stash store $(git stash create)
```

---

Under the hood `git stash [push]` does :

1. create a commit which stores the content of the index + worktree,
2. store that commit in a ref named `refs/stash` (previous stashes are actually the reflog of this ref),
3. clean up the files on disk.

If you look at [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-create), there are other subcommands to `git stash` :

- `create` creates a commit as in step 1, and outputs its sha on stdout
- `store` does step 2

(step 3 is `git reset --hard HEAD`)

Comment: Any explanation of what it does?

Comment: @DrAnonymous https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-create